# How can I do this menu using list and css?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6

I have a sort of menu like [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/554BT/), but how you can see the code is not so "well".

I'd like that margin between word and border is always 5px for example, for every word.

I know I should use List for this kind of stuff, but I don't know how to apply css style with cross-browser compatibility.

Can you give to me an example of that menu with List?

Comment: First of all, i do not recommend JSFiddle for CSS issues. It's specifying a Doctype which busts any chances of developing compatible CSS.

Comment: What are you talking about? You know you can change the Doctype on jsfiddle to whatever you want to check the compatibility?!

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: What *are* you talking about? jsFiddle defaults to the HTML5 doctype, which triggers Standards Mode. Perhaps you're talking about the reset stylesheet that's included by default? You can turn this off by unticking "Normalized CSS".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/554BT/3/

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Incredible</li>
    <li>One</li>
</ul>

.menu { 
    width:545px;
    float:left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none
}
.menu li {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0 15px;
    border-left: 2px solid red
}
.menu li:first-child {
    border: 0
}
```

Comment: Yes it rocks, but in fact the space between border and word is not the same. Do you know what I mean? This is what I'm looking for :)

Comment: @kwichz: I changed my answer.

Comment: Yeah it rocks :) P.s. that padding: 0 15px; is it cross-browser? because I use to put padding-left, padding-right, and so on...

Comment: @kwichz: Yes, the `padding` shorthand is supported in all browsers. For more info: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200502/efficient_css_with_shorthand_properties/ - and if you're wondering, `:first-child` is supported in IE7+ (and all modern browsers)

Comment: ah so on IE6 this code won't works. Not so good :( Any other way?

Comment: [Are you sure you care about IE6?](http://ie6countdown.com/) The only problem in IE6 will be that the first item also has the `border-left` - not exactly a tragedy. If you're sure you need this to work in IE6, you can fix it with a tiny change, like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/554BT/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/554BT/4/)

Comment: Thanks! I'll use the last version I think :) (just a class) :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would do it, keeping it as easy (simple) as possible. It probably doesn't get any less complex than this:

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Incredible</li>
    <li>One</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    list-style-type: none; 
}
#menu li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    border-left: 2px solid red;
} 
#menu li:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
```

DEMO: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YPFZs/1)

Comment: `:last-child` (CSS3) doesn't work in IE8, which is unfortunately widely used. You should use `:first-child` (CSS2) instead where possible, because it works in IE7+. Of course, you could just do what I had to do in a comment on my answer because the OP apparently cares about IE6 :/

Comment: OMG, IE6, seriously? :( I agree with your `:last-child` and `:first-child` and have changed my answer accordingly, but IE6 doesn't suit in my answer as I tried to give the least complex answer. Including IE6 compatibility completely destroys that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Listmatic](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/) for examples of all the basic list layouts.

Looks like you want something like [this one](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/horizontal36.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

fiddle:[http://jsfiddle.net/anish/Laqqn/](http://jsfiddle.net/anish/Laqqn/embedded/result/)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .menu
    {
        width:500px;


    }
    .menu li
    {
        width:100px;
        text-align:center;
        float:left;


       border-right:1px solid red;

    }
    </style>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Incredible</li>
        <li>One</li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: A couple of comments: you need to get rid of the right border on the last `li`. If you specify `float: left`, then you don't need to explicitly write `display: block`.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS3 example, not really cross browser as it uses CSS3 pseudo-selectors
[CSS3 List menu](http://jsfiddle.net/pedrocorreia/u84wG/)

This other example uses a pipe character to separate the links and is cross browser safe:
[CSS2 List menu](http://jsfiddle.net/pedrocorreia/ARYR6/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Space between the borders do this =

Put a border on the right side of the li and the second button put a border on the left side of the li.

Now add margin-left (or margin-right) and see it expand.

This worked in my case.

Good luck.